# Java keeps using file after writer has closed

Tags: java, c#

Just made a java program that writes something to a file it receives from a phone,
The file gets written and I want to read that file using a c# client, but when trying to read the file, I get the error: File is in use by another process even though I made sure I closed the file writer...

This is the java code for the server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class VRSC {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    File file = new File("C:/Users/"+username+"/Desktop/VRemote.cmd");


    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5665);
        System.out.println("server started on port 5665");
        System.out.println("Please connect to: " + ip.getHostAddress());
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }catch(Exception e){} //read & display the message
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputS­tream()));
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        String mes; 
        while(true){
            if (in1.hasNext())
            {   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());


                mes=in1.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Command Received: "+mes);
                fw.write("VCommand: " + mes);
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can let the server write to the file but allow the c# client to read it and change it right after?

Comment: Always close files in the finally block, and not the catch block.

Comment: And remember to call file.Close(). You only close the filewriter.

Comment: @Dyrborg - if there was a `finally` block, `fw` would be out of scope in it. It is not even opened in the `try` so `finally` doesn't apply to it, and in any case a "try with resources" would be more appropriate. Also, `file` is of type `File`, and has no `close()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop inside the catch, you check if `in1` has an available word. But then wait for a full line. What if you receive a word(with an ending space), but no the EndOfLine character ? Your java thread will wait on the `nextLine()`, with the FileWriter opened.

=> Try with the `FW` creation after the `nextLine()` call, or use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()`

Also, as stated in comments, always call `close()` in finally blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: What are you trying to accomplish? Looks pretty uncommon what you are trying to do.

Second: Let me give you an answer. I seem to have encountered this problem before many many years ago. At that time it ran on some kind of Windows OS. It turned out that a `close()` operation will just inform the OS about termination of any future operations on that file but nothing more. The OS would do some internal cleanup in response but might delay this cleanup if a bit of I/O occurs on the current machine. Therefor you can not rely on really having the file closed whenever you call `close()`. This will result in the effect you noticed: When some other process tries to read the file you might run into an error. So this is not a Java issue, it is a general issue with Windows operating systems. (With other operating systems you might have similar issues of course: It is a general issue regarding internal asynchroneous operating system tasks.)

The only solution I found was to give the Windows operating system some time to realy close the file. As far as I remember a delay of 5 seconds was sufficient even under heavy I/O load. Therefor do the following in the C# program:

- Start the C# process and notify it about the new file
- Let this C# process sleep for 5 seconds
- Run a loop:

  - Try to open the file
  - On success: proceed as planned and perform your task with the data
  - On error: sleep for 1 second and repeat the loop

(Of course this solution will ONLY work on Windows where file-I/O typically is blocking the file.)

If you have a better solution, I'd be interested in reading it. This one was the solution we implemented, and it worked very well.

Writing files on Windows will typically prevent reading the same file by other processes. There might be ways to get around this in Java by diving deeper into Java I/O. But typically it is not worth the effort compared to the simplicity of the solution above. So if you do not really have some kind of need to pick a different solution, consider implementing the solution I presented here.

Comment: I'm making a remote connection to a Gta V mod ;) the phone app sends a command to the server which saves it to a file, then the mod reads it and executes it in game. about the delay, Someone else made this as well but since he didn't want to release his source so I made a new one myself however that one did not have a delay and c# read the file instantly as it was changed! I'm trying to find a solution for it though, his fix was on the server side as I can't see anything special in his c# code

Comment: I do not know anything about Gta V mods, but in general that kind of solution pattern is a security risk. I might be wrong here because - as I said - I do not know anything of the application domain you are working in here, but if clients issue commands they **ALWAYS** should be checked to not be malicious. Please have that in mind. As far as I understand your code allows clients to directly send commands to a server which executes them directly. This _might_ not be a very good idea regarding security.

Comment: It' be hard to speed up the process if you rely on files. You could reduce the waits, but that's it. You will require a different kind of technical approach if you want to remove the delay. Files are typically not a very good idea for interprocess communication. And this - IPC - is what you are trying to do as far as I understand: Communicating data from a Java program to a C# program. Why do you use Java at all in your case? Seems unnecessary to me. A C# server process could receive text data as well as a Java server process.

Comment: Regardless of your problem presented here and my solution please listen to what Benoît is saying.

Comment: I use java because GTA V loads this mod and the game doesn't really like sockets and it doesn't like threading either, if it sees something it doesn't like, it crashes instantly